# radare2 memory changing in debug mode

Tags: radare2

I have tiny program:

```
        0x08048080      66a1a0900408   mov ax, word loc.name       
        0x08048086      66bbafbe       mov bx, 0xbeaf
        0x0804808a      66891da09004.  mov word loc.name, bx    ; [0x80490a0:2]=0xdead

        0x08048091      31c0           xor eax, eax
        0x08048093      66a1a0900408   mov ax, word loc.name       
        0x08048099      b801000000     mov eax, 1
        0x0804809e      cd80           int 0x80
        0x080480a0      ad             lodsd eax, dword [esi]
        0x080480a1      de00           fiadd word [eax]
```

when program changing memory:

0x0804808a      66891da09004  mov word loc.name, bx   ; [0x80490a0:2]=0xdead

memory dump (with px @ 0x80490a0) not changed

is there possible to view memory change in real time when debugging?

thanks!

Comment: did you open your file in write mode or did you switch to one?

Comment: i did open in debug mode, but openning in write and debug mode does not work too

Comment: I understand your question better now, but running shows correct behavior - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've run the following on the latest r2 from git:

> r2 -d ./example

after setting the breakpoint on main and running to it I'm getting the following disassembly:

```
0x004004a6 b    668b04252810.  mov ax, word [loc.name]     ; [0x601028:2]=0xdead
0x004004ae      66bbafbe       mov bx, 0xbeaf
0x004004b2      66891c252810.  mov word [loc.name], bx     ; [0x601028:2]=0xdead
0x004004ba      31c0           xor eax, eax
0x004004bc      668b04252810.  mov ax, word [loc.name]     ; [0x601028:2]=0xdead
0x004004c4      b801000000     mov eax, 1
0x004004c9      cd80           int 0x80
```

The memory location shows, `0xdead @ 0x601028`.

After executing 3 step instructions. This is what I get when running `px @ 0x601028`

```
:> px@0x601028
- offset -   0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F  0 1  0123456789ABCDEF01
0x00601028  afbe 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ..................
```

So the change is reflected in memory but also when I check the disassembly

```
 0x004004a6 b    668b04252810.  mov ax, word [loc.name]     ; [0x601028:2]=0xbeaf rbx
 0x004004ae      66bbafbe       mov bx, 0xbeaf              ; rbx
 0x004004b2      66891c252810.  mov word [loc.name], bx     ; [0x601028:2]=0xbeaf rbx
 ;-- rip:
 0x004004ba      31c0           xor eax, eax
 0x004004bc      668b04252810.  mov ax, word [loc.name]     ; [0x601028:2]=0xbeaf rbx
 0x004004c4      b801000000     mov eax, 1
 0x004004c9      cd80           int 0x80
```

Now there's `0xbeaf @ 0x601028`.